# Storing Objects in columns using Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, orm, jpa

Is it possible to store something like the following using only one table?  Right now, what hibernate will do is create two tables, one for Families and one for people.  I would like for the familymembers object to be serialized into the column in the database.

```
@Entity(name = "family")
class Family{

    private final List<Person> familyMembers;

}

class Person{

   String firstName, lastName;
   int age;

}
```

Comment: This is not clear. If you're seeing familly as a group of person, then you need a new table for familly, except if you represent the familly with a simple type like an integer or a string.

Comment: OT: That would be a bad design.

Comment: If a family has 3 members, what value would you expect to see in the database column?

Answer (score 14):

This is an horrible design and I'm really not recommending it (you should just create another table) but it is possible.

First, you'll need to use a `byte[]` attribute to hold a serialized version of the list of persons that will be stored in a BLOB in the database. So annotate it's getter with `@Lob` (I would make the getter and setter `private` to not expose them). Then, expose "fake" getter and setter to return or set a `List<Person>` from the `byte[]`. I'm using [`SerializationUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) from Commons Lang in the sample below (provide you own helper class if you don't want to import this library) to serialize/deserialize on the fly to/from the `byte[]`. Don't forget to mark the "fake" getter with `@Transcient` or Hibernate will try to create a field (and fail because it won't be able to determine the type for a `List`).

```
@Entity(name = "family")
class Family implements Serializable {

    // ...

    private byte[] familyMembersAsByteArray;

    public Family() {}

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "members", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
    private byte[] getFamilyMembersAsByteArray() { // not exposed
        return familyMembersAsByteArray;
    }

    private void setFamilyMembersAsByteArray((byte[] familyMembersAsByteArray() { // not exposed
        this.familyMembersAsByteArray = familyMembersAsByteArray;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Person> getFamilyMembers() {
        return (List<Person>) SerializationUtils.deserialize(familyMembersAsByteArray);
    }

    public void setParticipants(List familyMembers) {
        this.familyMembersAsByteArray = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) familyMembers);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make the `Person` class `Serializable` and to add a real `serialVersionUID` (I'm just showing a default here):

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // ...

   private String firstName, lastName;
   private int age;

}
```

But, let me insist, this is an horrible design and it will be very fragile (changing `Person` might require to "migrate" the content of the BLOB to avoid deserialization issues and this will become painful. You should really reconsider this idea and use another table for the `Person` instead (or I don't get why you use a database).

Comment: why can't you use database person, maybe because using it is pointless? If all I need is store a list of something, I don't need to put it in separate database.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Type(type = "serializable")
private List<Person> familyMembers;
```

if you can't use hibernate annotations try this:

```
@Lob
private Serializable familyMembers;

public List<Person> getFamilyMembers(){
    return (List) familyMembers;
}

public void setFamilyMembers(List<Person> family){
    familyMembers = family;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but This is not a JPA annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the property with `@Column` and define the type to be `ArrayList`, not just `List`. And make `Person` implement `Serializable`.

But you should do this only if your motives are very clear, because this is the correct solution in some very rare cases. As Pascal noted, if you ever have to change `Person` you'll have headaches.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this would fail with a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob`

Comment: yes, I took a look at one class of mine where I'm having the same situation - it works withotu Lob, and with specifying the concrete type (ArrayList). Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create pseudoproperty (getter and setter) which accepts/returns the serialized form, and annotate the `familyMembers` with `@Transient`. This would also need to annotate the getters, not fields, for all other properties.