# Persist DOM tree with JPA as String

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, dom, jpa

I have the following problem. I have a JPA Entity containing a property of type org.w3c.dom.Document. I can't and I also don't want to persist each object of the DOM tree individually. What I rather want is converting the XML represented by the DOM tree to a String and save this String to the database. When I load the object back in I want my object to parse the DOM tree and reinitialize the property. Is this possible with JPA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible.

What you need to do is treat the dom tree as a [custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828675/how-to-use-custom-type-in-jpa-column).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that is exactly what I wanted to avoid. The org.w3c.dom class hierarchy is rather intricate and I don't want to specify how to persit it as objects to a database. But no problem. I found my answer after some additional searching and reading.

Comment: You are assuming I was saying define the dom as a custom type, I was not: I was saying define your own representation as such, even if it's just a string.

Comment: But this only works with Hibernate. I need to stick to plain JPA.

Comment: Recap: I pointed you to that, you said no, then you edited your answer to take the same approach, but now you don't like that either? Hilarious. Yeah, you are right about it being Hibernate only. Dude, just make a class! Call it something like Dom (in your package) and then just have a Constructor that takes the tree, and one property inside that's a string. That will get persisted properly?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional search I finally found the answer. You just need to tell JPA to save it as a Blob with the  xml document inside the  element.

EDIT:
As it turns out, this does not work. I think I found a working solution here: [Storing Objects in columns using Hibernate JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121860/storing-objects-in-columns-using-hibernate-jpa)