# string data, right truncation - Hibernate with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

So I've got an entity class working perfectly. Today I added a new field:

```
ButtonTargetBehavior buttonTargetBehavior;
```

ButtonTargetBehavior is an interface (which implements Serializable). Whenever I try to run my spring boot app now I get this

```
string data, right truncation
```

error which refers to that field (Yes, I actually save an instance of a class that implements the interface, for example:

```
public class RandomButtonTargetBehavior implements ButtonTargetBehavior
```

).

I use HSQLDB for testing and MySQL on production. What do I need to do?

Comment: Try using `@Type` annotation may solve your problem

Comment: Didn't work. I used it like @PRATHAP S
@Type(type = "com.package.class")

Comment: Fixed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121860/storing-objects-in-columns-using-hibernate-jpa . I think most proper solution is custom types though

Comment: How can you add interface as a field in Entity class? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @PRATHAPS It's an instance of an interface. Specifically a Behavior. Class & project can be found here: https://github.com/carloworks/masher/blob/master/src/main/java/com/carloworks/model/core/GameMode.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by [Storing Objects in columns using Hibernate JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121860/storing-objects-in-columns-using-hibernate-jpa). I think the most proper solution is custom types though.